# Table.getItem returns wrong item only in RHEL6

Tags: java, swt, rhel6

I've a weird issue,

I've a table with 2 columns and 3 rows
each cell text  can be edited at run time, when I edit the cell in the 3rd row second column I get the upper cell modified too with the same text
this only occurs on redhat6 . works fine with rhe5 and rhe4
editor of type TextCellEditor;

```
  TableItem item = table.getItem(textEditor.getControl().getLocation());
```

getItem method implementation in Table.class is :

```
public TableItem getItem (Point point) {
    checkWidget();
    if (point == null) error (SWT.ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT);
     int /*long*/ [] path = new int /*long*/ [1];
    OS.gtk_widget_realize (handle);
     if (!OS.gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos (handle, point.x, point.y, path,null, null, null)) return null;
    if (path [0] == 0) return null;
    int /*long*/ indices = OS.gtk_tree_path_get_indices (path [0]);
    TableItem item = null;
    if (indices != 0) {
        int [] index = new int [1];
        OS.memmove (index, indices, 4);
        item = _getItem (index [0]);
    }
    OS.gtk_tree_path_free (path [0]);
    return item;
}
```

I thought it might be my GTK library . I have GTK2 lib installed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the `OS` class? You shouldn't have to usually.

Comment: That is just copy of the source code within the `Table.class` of SWT.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Right, I should read the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is triggered because the `Text` inside the `TextEditorField` field has some margins or minimum size that does not fit in the cell, or the row height is calculated incorrectly.

However, I suggest that you do not try to find the table item that the text editor is pointing at by using the `getItem(Point)`, as there are probably other kinds of issues too, and this kind of behaviour cannot generally be guaranteed. I'd say that should be chiefly used to find "the one item that is being pointed to at by mouse." as in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362336/why-does-table-getitempoint-always-return-the-item-from-column-zero). Actually you could be count yourself being lucky that you actually find out this bug.

---

The quick-and-dirty solution would be to calculate the center of the `Text.getBounds()` and use that to find the item, that is:

```
Rectangle bounds = textEditor.getControl().getBounds();
Point location = new Point(bounds.x + bounds.width / 2, bounds.y + bounds.height / 2);
table.getItem(location);
```

---

But the better alternative, if you're running SWT >= 3.3, to use the [`TableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport(EditingSupport)`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewerColumn.html) to set the [`EditingSupport`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewerColumn.html) for each column, because with `EditingSupport` you can make the editor knowledgeable of which item it is editing within the table.