# SWT table: How to retrieve row number under mouse cursor?

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to retrieve a row number under the mouse cursor (as I need to display some relevant information in tooltip based on the mouse position).

I already found a way to compute the column number based on the cursor position ([Why does Table.getItem(Point) always return the item from column zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362336/why-does-table-getitempoint-always-return-the-item-from-column-zero)), however can't find out the row number.

```
final Table table = ...

table.addListener(SWT.MouseHover, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {      
        final Point point = new Point(event.x, event.y);
        final TableItem item = table.getItem(point);
        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_CNT; i++) {
            final Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(i);
            if (rect.contains(point)) {
                // now I'm in the right column
                ...         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Table` `indexOf` method:

```
Table table = ... your table

TableItem item = ... your item

int row = table.indexOf(item);
```